# Android - Gravity of Toolbar title isn't correct

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I'm trying to style the Toolbar in AppCompat, but the title goes on the top in the Toolbar.
In other Activities, this problem doesn't happen.
How to fix it?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9jtJ.png)

- OS: Android 6.0.1
- Device: Nexus 5

> styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Black" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">#304FFE</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppTheme.Preference</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppAlertDialog.Black</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AppTheme.Transition</item>
    <item name="wcToolbarTheme">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Black</item>
    <item name="wcDefaultPreferenceTextColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="wcMenuTintColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/AppAlertDialog.Black</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">?attr/wcToolbarTheme</item>
    <!-MaterialDrawer->
    <item name="material_drawer_background">?android:attr/windowBackground</item>
    <item name="material_drawer_primary_text">@color/black</item>
    <item name="material_drawer_selected_text">?attr/material_drawer_primary_text</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Black" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="titleTextColor">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.Black" parent="AppTheme.Black">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppTheme.Preference</item>
</style>
```

> Code fragment of Toolbar in the layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    style="?attr/toolbarStyle"
    app:theme="?attr/toolbarStyle"
    android:theme="?attr/toolbarStyle"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution: Setting the Gravity of a TextView for the title to CENTER in Java code.